# Add value to object, calculated from 2 other columns D3js

Tags: arrays, csv, object, d3.js

I am trying to add an element to each object in an array (read in from csv). The calculation comes from 2 other elements from that same object.

I now have seperate object and adds that to the end of the array, and not as I wish as element to each object.

Here's my code

```
    d3.csv("database.csv", function(error, data) {

            data = data.filter( function(row) {  //filter out inactive data
            return row['active']  !== "NO";
            });

            Angleabs = {'Angleabs': data.map( function (d) { //calculate absolute angle for use in a worldmap from longitude and latitude
            return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(+d.lon,2) + Math.pow(+d.lat,2)))
            })};

            data.push(Angleabs);

            console.log(data);
            });
```

Thanks,

Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Angleabs = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(+d.lon,2) + Math.pow(+d.lat,2))
 });
```

This does not rely on d3.js: loop through your array, consider any element `d`, and add a field `d.Angleabs` computed as you wanted.